# How to bind event to custom admin button (help with architecture)

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, event-observer, controllers

This is my first full Magento module so I'm in need of a fair amount of guidance. I've created a new admin page and I'm adding a custom button that will eventually trigger a database insert. For now I'm just trying to pass around a string. below is a description of what I have so far for this part of my project. I'm struggling with the flow and architecture that binds the different pieces.

I've stripped out unnecessary code for readability. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

- **What I have so far**

  - **BLOCK**: I defined a custom dispatch event (how do I bind this to button?)
  - **TEMPLATE** : has button with string value - choosing not to use layout.xml for the moment *Edit* : added onclick with controller as location
  - **CONTROLLER**: I'm struggling with this because my admin URL has a nonce key
  - **OBSERVER**: Can I use this to call my controller using the URL helper since I'm unable to access my controller directly? Or could I even just rely on the dispatcher to retrieve the word?

### Myblock.php

```
<?php

class Mycompany_Mymodule_Block_Mymodule extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  protected function _construct()
  {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('mymodule/mymodule.phtml');
    }

  protected function mymoduleButtonClick()
  {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_mymodule_onclick', array('word' => $myword));
  }

}
```

### Template.phtml

```
<body>
 <?php
 $button = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/widget_button');
 $button->setData(array(
   'label' => $this->__('My Button'),
   'type' => 'submit',
   'class' => 'button',
   'value'   => 'string to be processed',
   'onclick' => "setLocation('{$this->getUrl('*/controller/action')}')"
   ));
 echo $button->toHtml();
 ?>    </body>
```

### Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
    <events>
        <adminhtml_mymodule_onclick>
            <observers>
                <add_button_test>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>listen_for_button_click</method>
                </add_button_test>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_mymodule_onclick>
    </events>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
                <mymodule>
                    <use>admin</use>
                    <args>
                        <module>Mycompany_Mymodule</module>
                        <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                    </args>
                </mymodule>
            </routers>
        </admin>
</config>
```

### AdminController.php

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Mymodule_AdminController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function testAction()
    {
      // EXAMPLE ADMIN URL :
      // http://myurl/index.php/eventqueue/admin/index/key/cbccea8b07101bed49388ad190d4b14ed1b2df2c0491f3a2f52ed23a755f4af3/

      // The nonce key prevents me from using this action in the url without interference. Instead I'm redirected to the dashboard.

      // Others have mentioned the helper below. But I don't understand how to use it since I can get to this controller successfully.
      //Mage::helper('adminhtml')->getUrl('adminhtml/Mycompany_Mymodule/index');
    }
}
```

## Observer.php

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Mymodule_Model_Observer  
{
    public function listen_for_button_click($observer)
    {
        // $word_from_button = $observer->?????;
        // is ' $observer->' holding data defined in dispatch example: $observer->word
        Mage::log('observer test!', null, 'lindsaylog.log');
    }
}
 ?>
```